# execution reverted: SafeERC20: low-level call failed

Tags: python, solidity, web3js, web3py

I'm trying to get a flashloan using web3.py. I'm able to deploy the flashloan contract successfully but when I call the flashloan function it's giving me

> execution reverted: SafeERC20: low-level call failed' failed error. I have enough ether in my account.

Do I need to send some ether to my flashloan contract? But I don't think so the error is because of lack of ether to pay the gas fees. (Let me know if this is the case!)

Below is my code for flashloan

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "./aave/FlashLoanReceiverBaseV2.sol";
import "../../interfaces/v2/ILendingPoolAddressesProviderV2.sol";
import "../../interfaces/v2/ILendingPoolV2.sol";

contract FlashloanV2 is FlashLoanReceiverBaseV2, Withdrawable {
    constructor(address _addressProvider) FlashLoanReceiverBaseV2(_addressProvider) public {}

    function executeOperation(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata premiums,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    )
        external
        override
        returns (bool)
    {

        // Approve the LendingPool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount
        for (uint i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            uint amountOwing = amounts[i].add(premiums[i]);
            IERC20(assets[i]).approve(address(LENDING_POOL), amountOwing);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function _flashloan(address[] memory assets, uint256[] memory amounts) internal {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);

        address onBehalfOf = address(this);
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](assets.length);

        // 0 = no debt (flash), 1 = stable, 2 = variable
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            modes[i] = 0;
        }

        LENDING_POOL.flashLoan(
            receiverAddress,
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            onBehalfOf,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }


    function flashloan(address[] memory assets, uint256[] memory amounts) public onlyOwner {
        _flashloan(assets, amounts);
    }


    function flashloan(address _asset) public onlyOwner {
        bytes memory data = "";
        uint amount = 1 ether;

        address[] memory assets = new address[](1);
        assets[0] = _asset;

        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](1);
        amounts[0] = amount;

        _flashloan(assets, amounts);
   }
}
```

Comment: are you testing this using ganache mainnet fork?

Answer (score 5):

I think the error you are receiving is because you don't have the funds available to repay the flashloan + premiums at the end of the (flash) transaction.

Your logic doesn't generate any extra profit, and the funds you ask alone are not enought to pay the fee.